# Pin slider input value in bubble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a slider for a voting web app to be used on an iPad. When the user has their finger on the bubble the value is supposed to show up above the element(works fine). When the user doesn't have their finger on the bubble, I want to value to be inside the bubble. I got the current value to show up(it looks good when the value is 5) but I can't figure out how to stick it inside the bubble for every value.

Here's what I have in [Codepen](http://tinyurl.com/h2obl55)

Answer (score 0):

Try making these changes in your CSS:

```
#static-output {
  text-align: center;
}
```

And in your JS:

```
 h = figure / max * ($("#input-wrapper").width() - $("#reel").width() + 37) + 'px';
```

Now the 37 is hardcoded, and might have to be tweaked if you change the size of the slider, but this should do it. [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLRPbQ)